# systemd upgrade frozen on "removing any startup links for /etc/init.d/udev-mtab"

Tags: debian, testing, systemd

I am having an issue upgrading my VPS which runs latest Debian,
I decided to switch to testing branch to be able to use OpenSSH 6.7 (the current stable branch only brings 6.0 which lacks many ciphers and important to me functions).
And so after spending about 5 hours trying to get this work I have given up and come to ask for guidence here because no valid solutions has been found.
I tried to do `apt-get install openssh-server` but it only threw me unmet dependencies.

```
[root:~]# apt-get install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
lsof : Depends: libperl4-corelibs-perl or
             perl (< 5.12.3-7) but 5.20.1-4 is to be installed
openssh-server : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: openssh-client (= 1:6.7p1-3)
              Depends: openssh-sftp-server but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: xauth but it is not going to be installed
plymouth : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18) but it is not going to be installed
systemd-sysv : Depends: systemd (= 44-11+deb7u4) but 215-8 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

To which I do

```
[root:~]# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libicu48 libmagickcore5 libmagickwand5 libming1 libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-id128-0 libsystemd-journal0 pslib1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  init-system-helpers libperl4-corelibs-perl systemd-sysv
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  init-system-helpers libperl4-corelibs-perl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  systemd-sysv
1 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/88.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 342 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up udev (215-8) ...
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/udev-mtab ...
```

Up to this moment the process is stuck on this point, I've tryed restarting and changing source list and updatint apt, nothing seems to work.

I didn't risk doing a full reboot as that would mean shutting down a set of important services (Mail server, Web server and Game server), but if it's necesarry to do now, I will.